# No DNS for ec2 after outage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, vpc

There was a failure in the Sydney region of AWS. After a number of hours they came back up however there was no longer a DNS on the *.2 of my ip range (or at least it wasn't responding).

I've added a public DNS to my `/etc/resolv.conf` to fix the issues however I'd like to get the one on my subnet working. I've tried to ping the *.2 and it returns nothing (however it might be purposely blocking it). I know I can also enable the old DNS in my VPC however I'd prefer to get the original one working.

Short of recreating the whole VPC again in the hope to get it back I'm not sure what I can do. I've tried posting to the AWS forums however it just goes into redirect loop even after signing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after 48+ hours it has come back online without any intervention.